# How can I create prettier fixtures with manage.py dumpdata?

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I'm trying to get my Django fixtures printed in a prettier way.

I've outputting the fixtures:
    `python manage.py dumpdata >> fixture_app.json`

This creates a file with 1000's of characters all on one line.
When I try to view the file with my Text Editor( TextMate ), the Editor hangs.

Is there anyway that the fixtures can be exported in a prettier way using multiple lines?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can try:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --indent=2
```

it will be easier to read.